# QT qmysql driver not loaded

Tags: c++, qt, mysql-connector

I know there are already many topics on this forum about this problem but I did not manage to solve mine following them.

My configuration is the following:

QT Version : 5.14.2 - mscv2017_64

Compiler: mscv amd64

My problem is that my application does not load the libmysql.dll.
Here is what I have done:

I opened the command line MSCV 2017 64bits provided by qt and I initialized my environment using `vcvarsall.bat amd64`.
Then I have built the sql driver as explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql).

Here is the result of the qmake call:
[image]

Then, ran `nmake`and `nmake install` and in the folder `C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\plugins\sqldrivers`, I found the following files.
[image]

Then I added `libmysql.dll` in the folder where my the exe file of my application was created. I got this file from the mysql server installation folder `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib`.

Then I rebuilt my application, but I still have the same error appearing, saying that the driver was not loaded. I compiled using the `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` flag and I got as an output:

> "The plugin 'C:/Qt/5.14.2/msvc2017_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsqld.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
>            not a plugin
>   QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/Users/Thomas Bouchan/Documents/Personal/C++/SSVP/build-SSVP-project-Desktop_Qt_5_14_2_MSVC2017_64bit-Release/release/sqldrivers" ...
>   Cannot load library C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll: The specified module could not be found.
>   QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "C:/Qt/5.14.2/msvc2017_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlmysql.dll" : "Cannot load library C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll: The specified module could not be found."
>   QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
>   QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7"

From this I don't know what to do, as in the specified folder, the dll is there... Is it a question of 64 or 32 bits? Shall I build the driver with another compiler (not `amd64`?)?

Comment: *Cannot mix debug and release libraries*: It is not a 32/64bit problem, but a Debug/Release problem

Comment: I agree but what can be wrong? I am running my application in Qt creator in debug mode and qsqlmysqld.dll is the debug dll...

Comment: Ah I see it is another Plugin, the MySQL has later a different message. Looks like a dependend DLL cannot be found. Can you try load the `qsqlmysql.dll` in [dependency walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally manage to get it working.

There was no issue with the compilation of the drivers, but the problem came from the `libmysql.dll` file. I don't know what happened with this dll but when I replaced it with the one downloaded the archive [qsqlmysql.dll_Qt_SQL_driver_5.14.2_MSVC2017_64-Bit.zip](https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases/tag/qmysql_5.14.2). I only needed to replace the dll, not to use the plugins of the archive.

Opening the `qsqlmysqld.dll` with the dependency walker, I found out that two additional dlls files are required in `libmysql.dll`: `LIBSSL-1_1-X64.dll` and `LIBCRYPTO-1_1-X64.dll`. They can be found in the bin directory of the mysql server. In my case `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`.
Adding those files in the directory of the executable solves the problem. Thanks @king_nak for the tip!