# QSqlDatabase: no available drivers on the development computer

Tags: mysql, qt

I'm running QT Creator on Windows 10 and when I want to use MySQL, then it says.

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers:
```

It's missing drivers.

I have:

- MySQL worksbench
- MySQL server
- MySQL connector/C++
- And the whole MySQL package
- Deployed on Windows x64

So why does this not work?

Comment: You need to compile the QMYSQL plugin using the Qt sources

Comment: @drescherjm Yes. But how can I do that? I'm reading here, but I don't know where to look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html

Comment: I believe you need to download the source code for your version of Qt you have installed. In the source code there is the configure file that the documentation talks about.

Comment: @drescherjm But isn't there any easier way? I have installed QT creator and made a project.

Comment: You may be able to download the plugin however I am not sure.

Comment: Here is some other building links I found: [https://dev.to/f1r361rd/how-i-build-a-mysql-plugin-for-qt5-windows-mingw32-2kim](https://dev.to/f1r361rd/how-i-build-a-mysql-plugin-for-qt5-windows-mingw32-2kim)

Comment: This question shows successfully building the plugin with the command line executed: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322287/qt-qmysql-driver-not-loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322287/qt-qmysql-driver-not-loaded)

Comment: @drescherjm Why does this seems so difficult?

Comment: It actually looks pretty easy to me compared to other installs. However I have built Qt from source many times (several dozen) over the 13 years I have used it at work.

Comment: @drescherjm So to begin with, I need to open maintance tool?

Comment: I think you can install the source code from the online installer. I am not an expert at that part as I only use it when helping someone else or testing Qt-Creator. For my work projects I download the source code .7zip file and build Qt myself.

Comment: @drescherjm Do you think this is a solution? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows

Comment: Yes. The plugin dll is built from source in the second step.

Comment: @drescherjm Ok. So in this case my sqldrivers folder is at `C:\QT\6.1.2\mingw81_64\plugins\sqldrivers` and the `lib` folder for Mysql is at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib` Do I need to write `qt-cmake -G"Ninja"` ?

Comment: @drescherjm What should I write here `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<qt_installation_path>\<platform>`

Comment: You know what. I'm quitting using MySQL from now.

Comment: There should be a platform folder in the your Qt binaries. I don't have Qt installed from the installer on the current PC so I can't tell you the default folder.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm trying insead to use MySQL Connector/C++ instead directly inside QT.

Comment: @drescherjm No wait. I will give QT one more chans. I will install QT 5.12.2 instead of latest QT 6.1.12 version

Comment: @drescherjm When changing to QT5, then I got these now `QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7` :)

Comment: @drescherjm But running this command `qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"` does not do anyting. Only  response with `Usage: qmake [mode] [options] [files]`

Comment: You need to run that in the correct folder of your Qt source code  for the version of Qt you have installed. I suspect you are not in the correct folder. In the documentation: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows) it has `cd %QTDIR%\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers` but that requires QTDIR to be set as an environment variable to the location of Qt. You can instead use the path of Qt.

Comment: @drescherjm Is this correct ? `C:\QT\5.12.11\mingw73_64\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"`

Comment: @drescherjm I don't have `qtbase\src`. Only `%QTDIR%\plugins\sqldrivers`

Comment: @drescherjm Yes `%QTDIR%` set as an enviroment variable like this https://youtu.be/XiMplRfuFJc?t=301 I can call `qmake` from everywhere

Comment: Does `C:\QT\5.12.11\mingw73_64\plugins\sqldrivers`  contain a .pro file and source code or is that just dlls and libraries.

Comment: @drescherjm Got it almost working right now. So I open a new question. Se here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68740798/mysql-connector-c-and-mysql-connector-c-does-not-work-with-qt

Comment: @drescherjm Now I get it working. Thank you so much!