# MySQL Connector/C and MySQL Connector/C++ does not work with QT

Tags: qt, mysql-connector

I have QT5 installed and I want to install QMYSQL. So I followed this manual. It's seems very simple, but still, nothing happens.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows

First I have `%QTDIR%` working and I have installed MySQL Server 8.0 64-bit with MySQL Connector/C++. I also downloaded MySQL Connector/C and then I run the following commands.

```
MySql .................................. no
```

As you see. Non of them understand that MySQL is installed. Why?

Here I'm trying with `MySQL Connector C 6.1`

```
C:\QT\5.12.11\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/lib"

Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'mingw32-make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'mingw32-make install'.
Qt will be installed into 'C:\QT\5.12.11\mingw73_64'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

Here I'm trying with `MySQL Server 8.0`

```
C:\QT\5.12.11\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"

Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'mingw32-make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'mingw32-make install'.
Qt will be installed into 'C:\QT\5.12.11\mingw73_64'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.


C:\QT\5.12.11\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Just paste .dll files everywhere.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeErME39zvw&ab_channel=JanN.
https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver

Comment: This video is not available anymore